# Upper Bound on Difference of Expected Values of Poisson Binomial Distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, reference-request, expectation

Let $X,Y$ be $2$ [Poisson Binomial Distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution) supported on $[n] = \{i | i \in \mathbb{Z}, 0\leq i\leq n \}$. Denote by $d(X,Y)$ their [total variation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures). I would like to find an upper bound
on the absolute value of the difference of their expected values, assuming that $d(X,Y) \leq \epsilon$, where $0<\epsilon<1$.

After some experimenting in R it seems that 
\begin{equation}
|\mathbb{E}[X] - \mathbb{E}[Y]| \leq \epsilon \log n
\end{equation}
holds with probability at least $9/10$, which maybe means that the correct bound lies in  $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon \log n)$.

References to such bounds or ideas on how to prove this bound (or a similar one) would be very helpfull.

Comment: Do you have an explicit expression for the total variation in terms of probability vectors of the two distribution, or are you thinking about the total variation between the distribution of the underlying binary vectors, i.e. the ell_1 norm of the difference between the two probability vectors? I am curious how you simulated the closeness in total variation in R.

Comment: What do you mean that $\lvert\mathbb{E}[X]-\mathbb{E}[Y]\rvert\leq\epsilon\log n$ with probability at least 9/10?  There's no probability here, since you've taken expectations.

Comment: @NickPeterson I mean that this inequality holds for $90\%$ of the tests.

Comment: @passerby51 I do it the dumb way, that is I create a vector $(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$ and then tweak (by adding or subtracting small values) a random number of $p_i$'s to produce the vector $q$. Then I calculate corresponding pmf's using https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/poibin/index.html and compare their expected value and total variation distance.

Comment: @vkonton, analytically, it is hard to get a handle on the total variation you are asking whereas the difference in expectation is quite straightforward. All of these things are controlled by $\sum_i | p_i - q_i|$ for example.

Comment: @passerby51, in my setting the variance of $X,Y$ is pretty small (let's say $Var(X), Var(Y) \leq 1$). My intuition is that in order to get $X,Y$ to be $\epsilon$-close, their expected values should also be pretty close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X,Y$ be two Poisson Binomial Distributions.
   Let $\mu_x = \mathbb{E}[X],\ \mu_y = \mathbb{E}[Y],\
   \sigma_x^2 = Var(X),\ \sigma_y^2 = Var(Y)$.
   For any $\epsilon>0$, such that
   $\sigma_x^2 ,\sigma_y^2 \geq n\epsilon\ln(n/e)/2$,
   if $X,Y$ are $\epsilon$-close, that is $d(X,Y) < \epsilon$, then
\begin{align*}
\left| \mu_y - \mu_x \right| \leq
      \frac{ 2\epsilon + \sqrt{\epsilon}
      \left(\sigma_x +\sigma_y\right) }{1-\epsilon}
      = O\left(\sqrt{\epsilon} (\sigma_x +\sigma_y)\right)
      \end{align*}

**Proof**

Let $Z$ be a random variable. Denote by $F_z,\ \bar{F}_z$
   the cumulative and the complementary cumulative distribution of
   $Z$ respectively. Define $\delta_i :=F_x(i) - F_y(i)$.
Without loss of generality assume that $\mu_y > \mu_x$.
\begin{align*}
   \mu_y - \mu_x &=
   \sum_{i=0}^n \left(\bar{F}_y(i) - \bar{F}_x(i)\right) \\
   & = \sum_{i=0}^n\left(F_x(i) - F_y(i)\right) \\
   &\leq \sum_{i=0}^{\mu_x-\sigma_x/\sqrt{\epsilon}} \delta_i
   + \sum_{i=\mu_x-\sigma_x/\sqrt{\epsilon}}^{\mu_y+\sigma_y/ \sqrt{\epsilon}}
   \delta_i + \sum_{i=\mu_y+\sigma_y/\sqrt{\epsilon}}^{n} \delta_i
\end{align*}
   The contribution of the lower tails of $X,Y$ is at most $\epsilon$
   \begin{equation*}
      \sum_{i=0}^{\mu_x-\sigma_x/\sqrt{\epsilon}} \delta_i
      \leq  \sum_{i=0}^{\mu_x-\sigma_x/\sqrt{\epsilon}} F_x(i)
       \ \leq\ n F_x\left(\mu_x -\sigma_x/\sqrt{\epsilon}\right)
       \ \leq\ n \exp\left(-\frac{2\sigma_x^2}{n\epsilon}\right)
      \ \leq\ \epsilon
   \end{equation*}
   For the second inequality we used the Chebyshev inequality.
   for the last the fact
   $\sigma_x^2\geq n\epsilon \ln\left(n/\epsilon\right)/2$.
   In the same way one can show that the contribution of the upper
   tails is at most $\epsilon$.

Notice that $d(X,Y) \leq \epsilon$ implies
   $\left| F_x(i) - F_y(i) \right| \leq \epsilon$ for every $i$.
   \begin{equation*}
   \sum_{i=\mu_x-\sigma_x/\sqrt{\epsilon}}^{\mu_y+\sigma_y/ \sqrt{\epsilon}}
      \leq \left( \mu_y +\sigma_y/\sqrt{\epsilon} -
      \mu_x + \sigma_x/\sqrt{\epsilon} \right) \epsilon
      = \left(\mu_y - \mu_x\right) \epsilon
      + \left(\sigma_x +\sigma_y\right) \sqrt{\epsilon}
   \end{equation*}
   Use the above inequalities to obtain
   \begin{align*}
      \mu_y -\mu_x &\leq 2\epsilon +  \left(\mu_y - \mu_x\right) \epsilon +
       \left(\sigma_x +\sigma_y\right) \sqrt{\epsilon} \\
      & \leq \frac{ 2\epsilon + \sqrt{\epsilon}\left(\sigma_x
      +\sigma_y\right)}{1-\epsilon} \\
      & = O\left(\sqrt{\epsilon} (\sigma_x +\sigma_y)\right)
   \end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Let $(p_1,\dots,p_n)$  and $(q_1,\dots,q_n)$ be the probability vectors underlying trial vectors $X^n = (X_1,\dots,X_n)$ and $Y^n = (Y_1,\dots,Y_n)$, and let $X = \sum_i X_i$ and $Y = \sum_i Y_i$.

We have

\begin{align}
|\mathbb E X - \mathbb E Y| = | \sum_i \mathbb E(X_i-Y_i)| 
&= | \sum_i (p_i - q_i)| \\
&\le \sum_i | p_i - q_i| \\
&=  \sum_i d_{TV}(X_i,Y_i)  
\end{align}

Dealing with total variation of the product measure $d_{TV}(X^n,Y^n)$ is not easy (and perhaps the same holds for $d_{TV}(X,Y)$. Either the Hellinger distance or Kullback-Liebler divergence are better behaved under products.

It might be easier to bound everything in terms of $\| p - q\|_1 = \sum_i |p_i - q_i|$. Assume that this quantity is $\le \epsilon$, then we have $|\mathbb E  X - \mathbb E Y| \le \epsilon$ and
\begin{align}
[d_{TV}(X^n,Y^n)]^2 \le 2 H^2(X^n,Y^n) \le 2 \sum_i H^2(X_i,Y_i) \le 2 \sum_i d_{TV}(X_i,Y_i) \le 2\epsilon.
\end{align}

**EDIT.** Assume $d_{TV}(X^n,Y^n) \le \epsilon$. Then, $\alpha_j := \frac{p_j}{1-p_j} \prod_{i=1}^n (1-p_i)$ is the probability of $X_j = 1$ and $X_i = 0, i\neq j$. Similarly, define $\alpha := \prod_{i=1}^n (1-p_i)$ (the probability of all of them being zero) and $\beta_j =  \frac{q_j}{1-q_j} \prod_{i=1}^n (1-q_i)$ and $\beta := \prod_{i=1}^n (1-q_i)$.

From the assumption it follows that $\sum_j |\alpha_j - \beta_j| \le \epsilon$ (the event that exactly one of them is equal to 1), and $|\alpha - \beta| \le \epsilon$. Then,
\begin{align*}
 \sum_j \Big( \frac{p_j}{1-p_j} - \frac{q_j}{1-q_j} \Big) &= 
   \sum_j \Big( \frac{\alpha_j}{\alpha} - \frac{\beta_j}{\beta} \Big) \\
   &= \sum_j \Big( \frac{\alpha_j}{\alpha} - \frac{\alpha_j}{\beta} + \frac{\alpha_j}{\beta}- \frac{\beta_j}{\beta} \Big)\\
   &= \Big( \frac1\alpha - \frac1\beta \Big)\sum_j\alpha_j +  
   \frac1\beta \sum_j\big(\alpha_j- \beta_j  \big)
\end{align*}
Assuming $\alpha,\beta \ge c^{-1}$ for some constant $c > 0$, we have $|\alpha^{-1} - \beta^{-1}| \le c^2 \epsilon$. We also have $|\sum_j \alpha_j| \le 1$. It follows that 
\begin{align*}
 \sum_j \Big| \frac{p_j}{1-p_j} - \frac{q_j}{1-q_j} \Big| \le 2 c^2 \epsilon + c \epsilon
\end{align*}
Consider the map $x \mapsto f(x):=x/(1+x)$  on $[0,1]$ which has derivative $(1+x)^{-2}$, hence Lipschitz with constant $1$ on $[0,1]$. We have
\begin{align*}
 |p_j - q_j| = \Big| f\Big(\frac{p_j}{1-p_j}\big) - f\Big(\frac{q_j}{1-q_j}\Big) \Big| \le \Big| \frac{p_j}{1-p_j} - \frac{q_j}{1-q_j}\Big|.
\end{align*}
It follows that 
\begin{align*}
 \sum_j \big| p_j - q_j \big| \le 2 c^2 \epsilon + c \epsilon.
\end{align*}
The condition $\alpha,\beta \ge c^{-1}$ seems to hold if $p_j,q_j \approx 1/n$ in which case both $\alpha,\beta$ approach $\approx e^{-1}$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: The thing is that I cannot assume that $\|p-q\|_1 \leq \epsilon$. I can  only assume  that $d_{TV} (X^n,Y^n) \leq \epsilon$.

Comment: @vkonton, I have added an argument. Please check for mistakes.

Comment: I have some trouble understanding why $|\alpha^{-1} - \beta^{-1}|\leq c^2 \epsilon$. Shouldn't that be 
$|\alpha^{-1} - \beta^{-1}| = | \frac{\beta-\alpha}{\alpha\beta} | \leq \epsilon/(\alpha\beta) \leq \epsilon/c^2$, since, $\alpha\beta \geq c^2$ ?

Comment: @vkonton, yes, you are right, that is a typo (fixed). I am assuming $c > 0$ is a constant so $c^{-2}$ is another constant.

Comment: The good thing is that with this bound I can handle the cases where
$p_i,q_i \leq 1/n$ or symmetrically $p_i, q_i \geq 1-1/n$. Unfortunately this bound is too bad otherwise. Nevertheless this bound is a decent starting point (and the Lipschitz trick was neat).

Comment: @vkonton, what is bad about it? Under that scaling it gives $d_{TV} = O(\eps)$ with no dependence on "n".

Comment: Suppose that $p_j,q_j \sim 1/2$. Then $\prod_j p_j \sim (1/2)^{n}$ which is extremely small, for big $n$, making $2c^2 \epsilon + c \epsilon$ very large.

Comment: @vkonton, that can't happen because you are assuming the variances are bounded by 1.

Comment: @vkonton, under assumption $\text{var}(X), \text{var}(Y) \le 1$ those probabilities behave more or less like $n^{-1}$, say if $p_i, q_i \le 1/2$ for all $i$.

Comment: You're right. My comment[1] was misleading. I actually need to handle also the case where the variance is not bounded by 1. I said that because my initial plan was to distinguish the two cases.

  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2045198/upper-bound-on-difference-of-expected-values-of-poisson-binomial-distributions/2045296?noredirect=1#comment4198655_2045198

Comment: @vkonton, OK... the case $p_i \approx 1/2$ would be very different since the distribution concentrates around $X = n/2$. You could consider these events then (half of the $X_i$ being zero and half of them being 1). Then a variant of this argument could go through. I don't think it would be easy to come up with an argument that covers all the cases at once...

Comment: @vkonton, Basically, you want to focus on events that contain most of the mass of the distribution. Maybe one can give a general argument based on concentration inequalities.

Comment: I don't think that this argument is valid assuming $d_{TV}(X,Y)<\epsilon$. The problem is that $d_{TV} < \epsilon$ does not imply 
$\sum_j |\alpha_j - \beta_j| <\epsilon$. Assuming $d_{TV} (X^n, Y^n) < \epsilon$ the arguments seems valid. I edited the proof accordingly.

Comment: @vkonton, it is valid. As I mentioned, all we are considering is the probability that $\sum_i X_i$ are equal to $1$ or $0$, which are controlled by the total variation on the distribution of the sums. I wasn't using $\sum_j |\alpha_j - \beta_j| \le \epsilon$. I was using $|\sum_j \alpha_j - \sum_j \beta_j| \le \epsilon$. Note that $\sum_j \alpha_j = P(X=1)$.

Comment: @vkonton, neither one implies $\sum_j|\alpha_j - \beta_j| \le \epsilon$.

Comment: You're right, I meant to bound it by $2\epsilon$. I am not sure that this is correct but: $d(X^n,Y^n) = \frac12 \sum_{t\in\{0,1\}^n}\Big|\mathbb{P}[X^n =t] - \mathbb{P}[Y^n=t]\Big|\leq\epsilon$. Using $\alpha_j=\mathbb{P}[X^n=(\overbrace{0,\ldots,0,}^{i-1}1,0,\ldots,0)]$ don't we deduce $\sum |\alpha_j -\beta_j| \leq 2\epsilon$ ?

Comment: I think that to use $\Big| \sum \alpha_j - \beta_j\Big|$ you  need the inequality $p_j -q_j \leq \frac{p_j}{1-p_j}-\frac{q_j}{1-q_j}$ which is not implied by $|p_j -q_j |\leq \Big| \frac{p_j}{1-p_j}-\frac{q_j}{1-q_j}\Big|$